# ruby - is there a way to add code to run after each method definition

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I understand that def is a keyword and can't be overridden.

But is there a way to call a method when a method gets registered with a class(passing in the name of the method being created?)

Answer (score 7):

That's what the [`Module#method_added`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Module%3amethod_added) hook method is for:

```
module Foo
  def self.method_added(meth)
    p meth
  end

  def bar; end
end

# :bar
```

Comment: So would this print the name of each method that was added to a class where this was mixed in?

Answer (score 3):

To create a mixin with that hook:

```
module Foo
  def method_added(method_name)
    puts "method #{method_name} added"
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Foo

  def some_method
  end
end
```

Notice that method_added is class method (strictly class Class instance instance method sic!), since it is defined in Module class. So we have to add it with extend so it goes to Bar metaclass.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

> class_instance.send(method_name)

should do it

Comment: Isn't that just the equivalent of object.method()  ? I'm looking to automatically cal a method every time I define a new method in a class.